# How to send the array of objects as a response back to AJAX call in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

This is the Comments Schema in mongoDB::

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
ClientId: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },

  AddtasksMain : [{
    AddtasksId: String,
    comments: [
      {
      username: String,
      comment: String
    }
]
    }]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comments', commentSchema);
```

This is the real data stored in mongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6f575bc747922658b976db"),
    "ClientId" : "5f6f575bc747922658b976da",
    "AddtasksMain" : [ 
        {
            "AddtasksId" : "gj1zeatygqy$s",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f6f580fc747922658b976e3"),
            "comments" : [ 
                {
                    "comment" : "This is my first comment.",
                    "username" : "Vicky Kumar",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6f582fc747922658b976e7")
                }, 
                {
                    "comment" : "This is my second comment.",
                    "username" : "Vicky Kumar",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6f5840c747922658b976e8")
                }, 
                {
                    "comment" : "This is my third comment!",
                    "username" : "Vicky Kumar",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6f584dc747922658b976e9")
                }, 
                {
                    "comment" : "This is my 4th comment.",
                    "username" : "Vicky Kumar",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6f588bc747922658b976ea")
                }, 
                {
                    "comment" : "This is my 5th comment.",
                    "username" : "Vicky Kumar",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6f5891c747922658b976eb")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

This is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/getComments",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    username: username,
    ClientId : ClientId,
    AddtasksId: AddtasksId
  },
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(response){
    if (response.status == '200') {
      location.reload();
}
}
});
```

This is my route code:

```
  router.route("/getComments").get(function(req, res) {

              Comments.findOne({ClientId: req.query.ClientId}, function(err, dataComments) {
              dataComments.AddtasksMain.forEach(element => {
                if(element.AddtasksId == req.query.AddtasksId)
                {
                 //   res.end('{"success" : "Comments uploaded succesfully", "status" : 200, "CommentData":element}');
}
})
})
})
```

The code is working. But I am unable to figure out how to send the response back to `AJAX` in handlebar with array of objects and then access them in handlebar by appending those comment datas to the divs.

So here what I want is that: all the `comments's array objects` to be sent in the form of response back to `AJAX` in success. Means I need to send the element here back to handlebar page as response in `AJAX`. So I thought maybe I can achieve that with either `res.end(), res.json()` or maybe with `res.send()`. I dont know? How to achieve that please?

These are the above code I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending response back to client, use Array.map to filter out your comments. This will give you new array. And then you can use `res.json(newArray)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` for example:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send(JSON.stringify(yourArray));
```